# 0 kb when upload and store image to server

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I have a table named `images`. It has two columns `id` and `image` (varchar300). I have this code upload.php :

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$image = $_POST['image'];
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql ="SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$id = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$id = $row['id'];
}
$path = "uploads/$id.png";
$actualpath = "/home/kinanday/public_html/$path";
$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
echo "Successfully Uploaded";
}
mysqli_close($con);
}else{
echo "Error";
}
```

this is upload.html :

```
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<button>Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
```

The problem is: it saves into my database but the image in my file manager in Cpanel is 0kb

I am using this code to integration to my android app which need an image with varchar type. So in my app does not show image anything because the image is 0KB.

Can anybody with your advance to fix my php. every answer is very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$image = $_POST['image'];` => `$image = $_FILES['image'];` and magic may happen. You need to use a submit type button also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Warning: base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/kinanday/public_html/image_content/upload.php on line 26 but the image size is stil 0Kb :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the $_FILES superglobal, as @Fred-ii- said.
but `$image = $_FILES['image']` is a array, see the options for it here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Examples:

```
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmpname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  // this is a temporary name that php uses on every upload he does.
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_error = $_FILES['image']['error'];
```

Comment: i have read that before, but i realy new for php script. Should i add new coloumn in my table (images) ? i only have teo coloums id and image in my table @leo_ap

Comment: you should add columns to store data that you'll need to use later. if you need to use the "size", then, create the "size" column. if you only want to show the image, then the "name" is more than sufficient and you can store it in this column that you already have.

Comment: dont forget to use the function move_uploaded_file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php as it is very important for php uploads. You must use it. basically you will need to: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "YOUR-UPLOAD-FOLDER/YOUR-IMAGE-NAME-PLUS-EXTENSION");

Comment: when i using `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` my file is not store on my upload folder, i get this warning Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/kinanday/public_html/image_content/upload.php on line 26
Successfully Uploaded

Comment: is the code [tmp_name] must have coloumn name too in my table?

Comment: this function take two parameters, the first is the temporary name of the uploaded file (this is handled by php internally), the second is the path to where you will send your file, including the file new name and its extension, example: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "my-uploads-folder/image001.jpg");

Comment: no, tmp_name is only a temporary name that you will only use to refer to the file when moving it to your uploads folder. There's no need to store it in a database

Comment: if i can give you more ceklist i will do!! Thanks it's work. now my image in upload folder have a size. thank you for your answer and sharing knowledge.