# FTP image upload doesn't work properly in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, codeigniter-3

I have a web application which is connected to a website. my web application runs in a **Ubuntu server(LAMP)**. in my web application, there is a function called add a new client. when adding a new client user have to set an image for the client. when a user clicks the save button, the image should upload to the Linux server itself and I'm sending the image to my **shared hosting server** where the website is hosted using **FTP**. **This perfectly works in my windows localhost (I'm using wamp server)**. but when I put my web application to the Ubuntu server, FTP image upload **works sometimes** and **sometimes it doesn't work**.

*this is my code*

```
private $config_ftp = array('hostname'=>'xxxx.com','username'=>'xxx@xxxxx.com','password'=>'xxxxx','passive'=>FALSE,'debug'=>FALSE,'port'=>21);

$source_original = $this->img_path['img_original'] . $file_name;     
$destination_original = $this->full_file_path['img_original'] . $file_name;

if($this->ftp->upload($source_original,"./assets".$destination_original)) {           
 $this->response['msg']="Images Uploaded successfully!";
 $this->response['status']=true;
}
```

when I check the destination folder after the upload it looks like this. The file size is 0kb. sometimes it gets uploaded properly. and I have to mention again this process works completely fine in **windows localhost**.

[image]

*Thanks.*

Comment: What are the sizes of the images being uploaded?

Comment: it's 7kb. this same image get uploaded sometimes and sometimes it's not.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any error. my gui keeps display about 1 minute and then  get closed.

Comment: make sure you have enough space left on ftp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there in my ftp_config.

what i had to do is set passive and debug as true

```
 private $config_ftp = array('hostname'=>'xxxx.com','username'=>'xxx@xxxxx.com','password'=>'xxxxx','passive'=>TRUE,'debug'=>TRUE ,'port'=>21);
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->ftp->upload() code is need to be shown to find actual problem.

in that if `$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];` $image_size is 0 that you have problem in image otherwise you can successfully upload it by `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "YOUR-UPLOAD-FOLDER/YOUR-IMAGE-NAME-PLUS-EXTENSION");` .

similar problem : [0 kb when upload and store image to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495375/0-kb-when-upload-and-store-image-to-server)

Comment: my image get uploaded to ubuntuserver itself which means size of the image is greater than 0. it get uploaded trough ftp as 0kb in tomy shared hosting server. and im not store my image in a database. im just upload images to a folder inside assets.